# Does the OP have the right to undo edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollback-wars, original-poster

I just saw the following comment:

> As the original author, you always have first dibs at undoing any edits. Glad you approve though :-) –  SomeMod♦

Is this right? This suggests that the OP is always in the right in an edit war, and that confuses me...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes and no, or "yes, to some extent".

Cases when I do agree with that statement:

1. Radical change to the post, e.g. changing the whole idea behind it.
2. Minor and **unimportant** syntax changes, e.g. changing "color" to "colour".
3. Trying to improve with own ideas of the editor, with which OP disagree. Kind of like #1 above.

In such cases, I believe OP has the right to edit, and I'll support it.

Cases when I disagree with the statement:

1. Editor removes "thanks", "hi", etc.
2. Editor improves formatting in the post.
3. Editor retagging properly.

In all above cases, and more (any truly valid edit), I would fight the OP for the sake of keeping the place clean and organized. Did it more than once, will do it again.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, the answer would be a yes.

If a user is making a question noticeably worse (or emptying the text, or some such thing) by rolling back edits that are made to a post, then I would flag the post for moderator attention, as they have abilities to lock post edits as they see fit.

If it's a small thing that doesn't make the meaning more unclear or whatnot, I would probably leave it, as it isn't as big of a deal.